# How to make the navigation-btns for @media screen desktop interactive by using JS?

Tags: javascript, button, navigation

For the tablet screen I managed to get the navigation buttons interactive, swiping an image and testimonial to the left/right by clicking. I want the same to happen in my desktop version.. The lay-out of the testimonial-section is different in desktop than in tablet. What is the right JS script to create the same effect??

```
                        <div class="MainDiv_tablet"> 
                            <h2>Lees</h2> <h2 class="bold">Testimonials</h2>
                            <div class="SecondDiv_tablet"> 
            
                                <div class="testimonials main"> 
                                    <img class="couple" id="Testimonial1" src="./Assets/Testimonials_1_mobile.png" alt="Testimonial 1">
                                    <div class="testimonial1">
                                        <p class="testimonial">
                                                We hoorden Strings 4 Weddings spelen op de bruiloft van onze vrienden. Het optreden was zo gaaf, dat het ons dagen is bijgebleven. Wij besloten ook klassieke muziek aan onze bruiloft toe te voegen. Toen we zelf gingen trouwen hebben we direct contact gezocht met Strings 4 Weddings. De organisatie verliep erg prettig en de uitvoering was fantastisch. Onze bruiloft zou nooit hetzelfde zijn geweest zonder jullie, erg bedankt!
                                        </p>
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
      
                                <div class="testimonials"> 
                                    <img class="couple" id="Testimonial2" src="./Assets/Testimonials_2_mobile.png" alt="Testimonial 1">
                                    <div class="testimonial2">
                                        <p class="testimonial">
                                                TESTTESTTEST
                                        </p>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>

                                <div class="testimonials"> 
                                    <img class="couple" id="Testimonial3" src="./Assets/Testimonials_3_mobile.png" alt="Testimonial 1">
                                    <div class="testimonial3">
                                        <p class="testimonial">We hoorden Strings 4 Weddings spelen op de bruiloft van onze vrienden. Het optreden was zo gaaf, dat het ons dagen is bijgebleven. Wij besloten ook klassieke muziek aan onze bruiloft toe te voegen. Toen we zelf gingen trouwen hebben we direct contact gezocht met Strings 4 Weddings. De organisatie verliep erg prettig en de uitvoering was fantastisch. Onze bruiloft zou nooit hetzelfde zijn geweest zonder jullie, erg bedankt!
                                        </p>
                                    </div>  

                                </div>

                                <div class="navigation-buttons">
                                    <div class="previous nav-btn"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 48px">chevron_left</i></div>
                                    <div class="next nav-btn"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 48px">chevron_right</i></div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>


    <div class="Title_desktop">
                                <h2>Lees</h2> <h2 class="bold">Testimonials</h2>
                            </div>
                                    <div class="MainDiv_desktop"></div> 
                                    <div class="SecondDiv_desktop">
    
                                        <div class="TestimonialDiv_desktop">  
                                            <div class="testimonials main">
                                                <img class="couple" id="Testimonial1" src="./Assets/Testimonials_1_mobile.png" alt="Testimonial 1">
                                            </div> 
                                            <div class="testimonials">
                                                <img class="couple" id="Testimonial2" src="./Assets/Testimonials_2_mobile.png" alt="Testimonial 2">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="testimonials">
                                                <img class="couple" id="Testimonial3" src="./Assets/Testimonials_3_mobile.png" alt="Testimonial 3">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
    
                                        
                                        <div class="Horizontal_swipe">
                                        
                                            <div class="navigation-buttons">
                                                <div class="previous nav-btn"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 48px">chevron_left</i></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="testimonials_text first">
                                                    <p class="testimonial">
                                                        We hoorden Strings 4 Weddings spelen op de bruiloft van onze vrienden. Het optreden was zo gaaf, dat het ons dagen is bijgebleven. Wij besloten ook klassieke muziek aan onze bruiloft toe te voegen. Toen we zelf gingen trouwen hebben we direct contact gezocht met Strings 4 Weddings. De organisatie verliep erg prettig en de uitvoering was fantastisch. Onze bruiloft zou nooit hetzelfde zijn geweest zonder jullie, erg bedankt!
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p class="referral">
                                                        <bold>Bram van Schagen</bold><br>
                                                        <i>2021 - married Brechtje de Koning, van Schagen</i>
                                                    </p>
                                            </div>
                                             <div class="navigation-buttons">
                                                <div class="next nav-btn"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 48px">chevron_right</i></div>
                                            </div>
    
                                        </div>
    
                                        <div class="testimonials_text">
                                            <p class="testimonial">
                                                TESTTESTTEST
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="testimonials_text">
                                            <p class="testimonial">
                                                We hoorden Strings 4 Weddings spelen op de bruiloft van onze vrienden. Het optreden was zo gaaf, dat het ons dagen is bijgebleven. Wij besloten ook klassieke muziek aan onze bruiloft toe te voegen. Toen we zelf gingen trouwen hebben we direct contact gezocht met Strings 4 Weddings. De organisatie verliep erg prettig en de uitvoering was fantastisch. Onze bruiloft zou nooit hetzelfde zijn geweest zonder jullie, erg bedankt!
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
    
                                    </div>







Script put inside the html for tablet and for desktop version:

<!-- SCRIPT TABLET -->
    <script>

    const previous = document.querySelector('.previous');
    const next = document.querySelector('.next');
    const images = document.querySelectorAll('.SecondDiv_tablet > .testimonials');
    const totalImages = images.length;
    let currentIndex = 0;

////
    // Event Listeners to previous and next buttons
    previous.addEventListener('click', () => {
      previousImage()
    })

    next.addEventListener('click', () => {
      nextImage();
    })
    
    
    // Function to go to next Image
    function nextImage(){

      images[currentIndex].classList.remove('main');
        if(currentIndex == totalImages-1){
            currentIndex = 0;
        }
        else{
            currentIndex++;
        }

      images[currentIndex].classList.add('main');
      
    }
    
    // Function to go to previous Image
    function previousImage(){

      images[currentIndex].classList.remove('main');
        if(currentIndex == 0){
            currentIndex = totalImages-1;
        }
        else{
            currentIndex--;
        }
    
      images[currentIndex].classList.add('main');

    }
    
    </script>

    <!-- SCRIPT DESKTOP -->
        <script>
    
        const previous = document.querySelector('.previous');
        const next = document.querySelector('.next');
        const images = document.querySelectorAll('.SecondDiv_desktop > TestimonialDiv_desktop > .testimonials');
        const totalImages = images.length;
        let currentIndex = 0;
    
        // Event Listeners to previous and next buttons
        previous.addEventListener('click', () => {
          previousImage()
        })
    
        next.addEventListener('click', () => {
          nextImage();
        })
        
        
        // Function to go to next Image
        function nextImage(){
    
          images[currentIndex].classList.remove('main');
            if(currentIndex == totalImages-1){
                currentIndex = 0;
            }
            else{
                currentIndex++;
            }
    
          images[currentIndex].classList.add('main');
          
        }
        
        // Function to go to previous Image
        function previousImage(){
    
          images[currentIndex].classList.remove('main');
            if(currentIndex == 0){
                currentIndex = totalImages-1;
            }
            else{
                currentIndex--;
            }
        
          images[currentIndex].classList.add('main');
    
        }
        
        </script>
```

Comment: Can you create a snippet to make sure we can experiment with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here:

`const images = document.querySelectorAll('.SecondDiv_desktop > TestimonialDiv_desktop > .testimonials');`

Dot is missed before `TestimonialDiv_desktop` to have a css-class selector, so it should be

`const images = document.querySelectorAll('.SecondDiv_desktop > .TestimonialDiv_desktop > .testimonials');`

Comment: Thanks @Alex for noticing! I added a . (dot) and cleaned the typo. Unfortunately the functionality still isn't working :( The reference to class=previous and class=next can both refer to the code for the tablet version as well as the code for the desktop version (both the buttons have the <div class="previous nav-btn"> and <div class="next nav-btn"> 

Perhaps this is where I did something wrong?

Comment: Ahh @Alex, I figured it out :D:D:D --> I had two <script> JS codes using the exact same 'const' Titles. So I realised both <script>s referred to the same declared titles in both scripts. I renamed all the 'const' Titles of the <script> used for the desktop version, and suddenly it worked :D Lesson learned

Comment: Cool! Good ot know you found a fix)

Comment: Perhaps you can help with figuring out how to add two functionalities/interactions on the same ' button click'? Any experience?

Comment: @lLizzy how do you want to trigger different actions on click?